# cloudera Hue can not view spark job history

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hue

Hue version:(3.8.1)

Hadoop version:2.5.2 Apache(none CHD)

Spark version:1.4.0 Apache(none CHD)

when click the spark job in job list to view detail, it raise the following error,while hadoop mr job is ok. 
could someone help me to figure out the where the problem is?

```
AttributeError at /jobbrowser/jobs/application_1435834774266_6980
'SparkJob' object has no attribute 'preemptedResourceVCores'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.1.7.35:10090/jobbrowser/jobs/application_1435834774266_6980
Django Version: 1.6.10
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'SparkJob' object has no attribute 'preemptedResourceVCores'
Exception Location: /tmp/tmpVD1cK8/jobbrowser/job.mako.py in render_body, line 191
Python Executable:  /data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/bin/python2.6
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    
['/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/bin',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/BabelDjango-0.2.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.9.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Paste-2.0.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyYAML-3.9-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pygments-1.3.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-1.0.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.7.6-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/configobj-4.6.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_auth_ldap-1.2.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_extensions-1.5.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_nose-1.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_openid_auth-0.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/djangosaml2-0.13.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/elementtree-1.2.6.post20050316-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/enum-0.4.4-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/guppy-0.1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kazoo-2.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kerberos-1.1.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lockfile-0.8-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.2.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Markdown-2.0.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pam-0.1.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/parquet-1.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyformance-0.3.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.13-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysaml2-2.4.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysqlite-2.5.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_daemon-1.5.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_ldap-2.3.13-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_openid-2.2.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytidylib-0.2.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytz-2015.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.6.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests_kerberos-0.6.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sasl-0.1.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson-2.0.9-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tablib-0.10.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/thrift-0.9.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib2_kerberos-0.1.6-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/core/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/indexer/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/liboauth/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/libopenid/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/librdbms/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/libsaml/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/libsentry/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/libsolr/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/libzookeeper/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipdb-0.1dev_r1716-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.10-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/coverage-3.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nosetty-0.4-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.6-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/windmill-1.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib64/python2.6',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/about/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/beeswax/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/filebrowser/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/hbase/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/help/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/impala/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/jobsub/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/metastore/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/oozie/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/pig/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/proxy/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/rdbms/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/search/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/security/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/spark/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/sqoop/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/useradmin/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/zookeeper/src',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/desktop/libs/libsentry/src/libsentry/../../gen-py',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/../../gen-py',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/hbase/src/hbase/../../gen-py',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/../../gen-py',
 '/data/resys/apollo/hue/hue/apps/proxy/src/proxy/../../gen-py']
```

Comment: It was tested with Spark 1.3, maybe something changed. We are integrating with 1.5 and will have a look soon https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2850

Comment: thanks, to add some information, hue is not able build with configuring spark 1.4.0, raise can not find relate maven resource for spark , and also did not work with spark 1.5.0, so I had to configure hue with spark 1.3.0, while actually run with 1.4.0.

Comment: Will see shortly if we can make compiling 1.3 also  work with 1.5, created https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2853